# Send String through a socket without closing the socket afterward

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I'm new to python and i want to send a string through a socket, I did some research and i go this code

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 1228))

string = "Hi"

s.sendall(string.encode('utf-8'))
input()
s.close()
```

There's one problem, nothing getting recieved on the server (C#) until the code pass the `input()` and the socket closes.

Is there anyway to send it without closing the connection.